# Parallel processing of huge number of small tasks

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a requirement where I have to process a huge number(in millions) of small CPU intense tasks parallely where each task takes around 10s. If I go with multiprocessing or multithreading I would be needing a huge number of instances of threads/processes. How do I go about solving this so that it takes a minimal amount of time?

Comment: Many computers at the time of writing have 4 to 12 cores. This means that one computer really can do 4-12 operations simultaneously. This might mean that you should divide the tasks into this number of queues and have each core crunch through one queue.

Comment: @quamrana but I have a million small tasks at hand. That's gonna take days if I process them in batches of 4-12. By small task I mean it's gonna take 10s to finish it

Comment: This is the usual conundrum. If tasks really do take 10s each then it will take 1 million x 10s / number of cores. To take less time you need to fiddle with the numbers: Have less tasks. Make each task take less time. Use more cores(ie use a cloud of computers). Unless the 10s is mostly waiting for something else, in which case just have lots and lots of `Thread`s.

Comment: @latish what about writing a small example to show the details of your problem? without them the most you can get from here is the comments you already got.

Comment: it is important to know whether these tasks are CPU or IO intensive. In the first case you'll have to stick with multiprocessing pool. In the latter one you can use multiple (sometimes hundreds) of threads or coroutines. The point is, the answer is really context dependent. Please provide more information.

Comment: If you have millions of tasks and limited computer power I recommend you get on with implementing _some sort_ of solution. Using my 5 core macbook you could already have processed 1800 tasks in the time since you asked this question. Don't wait too long for the perfect answer that may never come. :)

Comment: On a more serious note, is there any dependency between the tasks, or could you farm them out to multiple computers?

Comment: @Tony there is no dependency between the tasks.

Comment: What is each task doing? Why does each task take ~10 seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common pattern for this is to scale out horizontally. If you have 1,000,000 tasks @ 10 sec/task = 10,000,000 seconds for a single cpu to process or 166,667 minutes (2,778 hours or 116 days). Consider if you're on a multi core machine 4 cores that cuts it down to 29 days (rough estimate maybe need one core to handle queues...). 64 cores would be ~116 days / 64 = 1.8 Days.

If single machine performance doesn't meet your criteria you can scale out to multiple machines. All major cloud services offer queueing systems to make this easy/possible:

- Amazon SQS
- RabbitMQ
- Kafka
- NSQ
- Etc

Image property of https://anwaarlabs.wordpress.com/2014/04/28/message-queue-part-3-jms-domains/

Instead of being limited to a single machine each machine shares a connection to global queue where they (the consumers in the image) can pull tasks, allowing you to scale out to as many cpu cores as you need.

[image: multi node queueing system]https://anwaarlabs.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/messaging-queue.png

---

For CPU bound tasks multi-threading is a poor choice because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). If you only have a couple of million items it may reduce complexity to use python multiprocessing and a multiprocessing queue and scale out on a single machine (ie rent a 64 core machine from a cloud provider to process in a couple of minutes.  The strategy (scale up single machine vs scale out multi machines) depends on your workload size and performance constraints and cost constraints.